# Reverse an array using a generic method

Tags: java, collections

I have this code that I wrote as I was testing the generic methods, now I'm curious as to how I could reverse the output. I tried using collections to use the reverse method, and also tried using the index with a regular for loop but I got the index numbers instead of the actual index value. How could I reverse the order of the names?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = {
            "hi", "you", "there"
        };

        printArray(names);
    }

    public static <T> void printArray(T[] array){
        for(T el : array){
            System.out.print(el + " ");
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Show us the code where you tried to use indices.

Comment: for(int i=names.length-1; i>=0; i--)

Comment: Since you don't need to create an new array to reverse it, there is no complication to do this generic.

Comment: Note: generics are not needed for either the printing or reversing method, owing to the covariance of Java arrays. You can just use `Object[]` instead.

Comment: @JB Nizet All right

Comment: This really has nothing to do with generics. You should just replace the [enhanced for-loop (also known as foreach loop)](https://blogs.oracle.com/CoreJavaTechTips/entry/using_enhanced_for_loops_with) with an indexed loop.

Comment: i subbed the for each with a reg for loop using int i = array.length-1; i >=0; i--

Comment: Are you trying to reverse the array elements, or just print it in reverse?

Comment: but i get 0 1 2 instead of the string values

Comment: print in reverse

Comment: @user3803668 I suggest taking a step back and read up on arrays and how to loop over them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy. Traverse array in another order:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] names = { "hi", "you", "there" };

        printArray(names);
    }

    public static <T> void printArray(T[] array) {
        for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");

    }
```

Prints:

```
there you hi
```

Comment: there is my mistake!

Comment: i see what i was doing wrong, i was simply printing the "i" as the index, not the array[i] part

Comment: No there is no point of printArray() being generic, it is simply for my learning pleasure.

Answer (score 0):

You could use 
`Collections.reverse(Arrays.asList(names));`
This method runs in linear time.